# Raspberry Pi Linux Kernel debug -GDB scripts

Tags: linux-kernel, gdb

TL;DR

How to enable gdb-scripts for debugging Linux kernel running on QEMU aarch64 platform?

I wanted to build and debug Raspberry Pi 3b on QEMU. as per the documentation I have checked out the latest kernel source code

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux
```

and then built the kernel using

```
KERNEL=kernel8
make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- bcm2711_defconfig
make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- Image modules dtbs -j8
```

With `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y` in the `.config` file.

I wanted to inspect the early boot-log of the kernel using the `lx-dmesg` command.

To enable this, referring to the documentation https://docs.kernel.org/dev-tools/gdb-kernel-debugging.html, executed the command `make scripts_gdb` from the kernel root.

`make scripts_gdb`'s config step is asking mostly about x86 platform related config info against my expectation(none related to aarch64). But the build completed successfully and resulted in creating the needed `vmlinux-gdb.py` link file in the kernel root folder.

I have launched gdb and connected to the remote target. From gdb executed the following commands

`add-auto-load-safe-path <root-of-kernel-source>` and `source vmlinux-gdb.py`

This results in `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named zlib`

Am I executing `make scripts_gdb` command in the wrong way?

Any hint on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named zlib` - So you need to install Python zlib package.

Comment: @Tsyvarev If I run ```import zlib``` at python prompt, no error is thrown!

Comment: Make sure that GDB uses the same Python as you expect.